# How to install laravelcollective html in laravel 5 without using composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravelcollective

I'm using laravel 5.5 and I want to install laravelcollective without using composer. I have followed steps mentioned in other questions to install it in laravel 5.2 but it is generating the following error.
`Class Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider not found`

Please suggest the possible reasons for the error.

Answer (score 1):

Shashank Simha M R, I think the best way to go is by installing it via composer like this: `composer require laravelcollective/html "5.5.*"`. 
    Here, you just specify the version of the Laravel you've installed. Otherwise, composer will not be able to install it.

After that, you just update the config/app.php file like so:

1. Add the following line to the `$provider` array:
   `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class`
2. Then find the aliases array and add these two aliases to the aliases array:
   `'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class`,
   `'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class`,

   ```
           That is it!
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link:

https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html

download the package and extract it to /vendor/ folder so that you have this path

```
/vendor/laravelcollective/html/src/HtmlServiceProvider.php
```

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

```
  'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

And it should work.

Comment: I doubt this will work without updating Composer autoloading information.